# how to convert list of tuple into a string?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuple and I'd like to convert the list into a string of tuple pair separted by  comman. Not sure how to do it?

For example if I have list of this

```
a=[(830.0, 930.0), (940.0, 1040.0)]
```

I'd like to convert it to a string like this

```
b="(830.0, 930.0), (940.0, 1040.0)"
```

```
a=[(830.0, 930.0), (940.0, 1040.0), (1050.0, 1150.0), (1160.0, 1260.0), (1270.0, 1370.0), (1380.0, 1480.0), (1490.0, 1590.0)]
b=','.join(a)
b
----> 2 b=','.join(a)
      3 b

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found
```

Comment: Did you want `", ".join(str(x) for x in a)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [f-strings or formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)
and [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
a = [(830.0, 930.0), (940.0, 1040.0)]
b = f"{a}".strip("[]")
print(b)
# (830.0, 930.0), (940.0, 1040.0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Go over every element and put it in an f-string.

```
b=', '.join(f'{d}' for d in a)
```

Comment: Very Goood Idea

Answer (score 1):

if you want to convert the list of tuples to a string without the surrounding square brackets, you can use string manipulation to achieve that. Here's how you can do it:

```
a=[(830.0, 930.0), (940.0, 1040.0)]
b = ','.join(f'({x},{y})' for x, y in a)
print(b)
```

Comment: What if the tuples do not have a consistent length?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the string representation of a list you will notice that it starts with a left bracket and ends with a right bracket. So, just remove them as follows:

```
a = [(830.0, 930.0), (940.0, 1040.0)]
print(str(a)[1:-1])
```

**Output:**

```
(830.0, 930.0), (940.0, 1040.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This code combines a list of tuples into a single string, separating the tuples with commas. It then removes the trailing comma and prints the resulting string.

```py
a = [(830.0, 930.0), (940.0, 1040.0)]
output = ""
for i in a:
    output += str(i) + ","
output = output.rstrip(",") 
print(output)
```